# D1 Robot... lights up but nothing

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I have the Arduino shield described here, I have run the example code compiled to the device, both v1 and 1.1 example, and it shows nothing whatsoever on the screen.

https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Arduino_LCD_KeyPad_Shield_(SKU:_DFR0009)

Is there a special trick to initializing this or did I yet again get a lemon that will not display anything?

Comment: reduce the code to only the code for displaying something on LCD ..... only this line `LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);` and the code in setup() .... leave loop() empty .... does that display anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many cheap online shields, this one is a dud, in fact it looks like extended use would fry it if it did work - according to test code this chip is bad.
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=96747.0

Answer (score 1):

I got one of the D1 Robot version 1 from AllElectronic and I had to adjust the contrast before I could see the words on the display.

Comment: "I got one of the D1 Robot version 1 from AllElectronic and I had to adjust the contrast before I could see the words on the display." Thanks